# How to add user in linux pc using shell script in php

Tags: php, linux, shell

I am trying to add user into my LAN pc(ubuntu 14.04 ) but failed. 
Say for example :

mypc : 192.168.0.11
serverpc : 192.168.0.100

I can create user into "mypc" with shell scripting. But when I try to connect and add user into "serverpc" : its returning "Failed to add a user!". I am using PHP:

here is my method:

```
public function test_ldap(){

    $username = escapeshellarg('different');
    $password = escapeshellarg('different');
    #$udomain = 'edutechsolutionsbd.com';
    $u_domain = '192.168.0.100';
    $u_user = 'etsb';

    $output = exec("sudo shell_script/add_user.sh $username $password $u_domain $u_user 2>&1");
    #$output = shell_exec("/usr/bin/php -v");
    print_r($output);
    exit;

}
```

shell script ::

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to add a user to Linux system
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) 2007 nixCraft project <http://bash.cyberciti.biz/>
# This script is licensed under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# Comment/suggestion: <vivek at nixCraft DOT com>
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# See url for more info:
# http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-write-shell-script-to-add-user.html
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
if [ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]; then

username=$1
password=$2
u_domain=$3
u_user=$4

egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$username exists!"
    exit 1
else
    pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
    #useradd -m -p $pass $username
    sudo ssh $u_user@$u_domain "useradd -m -p $pass $username"

    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User is Created Successfully!" || echo     "Failed to add a user!"
fi
else
echo "Only root may add a user to the system"
exit 2
 fi
```

My question: How may I create user into my another pc in ubuntu ? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `exec()` function does not support running tasks with the `sudo` elevated privileges flag in my experience. I added the `www-data` user, which is the user that the web server should be running under, to the `/etc/sudoers` file which you open on the machine using the command `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers`, then below that line `includedir /etc/sudoers.d user_name ALL=(ALL)`.

Then I added the following line...

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Basically what you are doing is adding the www-data user to the sudoers list and allowing it to access the sudo command and run under elevated priveleges.

I should note however that this is a very dangerous change to make as it means that anyone could gain access to elevated privileges using the web server's user and this presents a huge risk if this is a public facing server so use it with extreme caution.